# How to extract a where clause expression tree from IQueryable

Tags: linq, lambda, entity-framework-6, expression-trees

I need to add an "Or" clause in a where clause dynamically, depending on some conditions to an existing IQueryable object.

Using ExpressionBuilder, I can compose a left and right Expression> but for that to wrok, I need to extract the Expression> from my IQueryable instance. 
Is it possible?

Sample code:

```
var list = _context.Set<T>().Where(x=>x.Id == 1);

if(someValue)
{
    var leftExpression = list.???? //I would extract the Expression<Func<T, bool>> here
    var orExpression = (T x) => x.Status == 1;

    var newWhereClause = ExpressionBuilder.Or(leftExpression, orExpression);
    list = list.Where(newWhereClause);
}
```

The ExpressionBuilder code was taken from this link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/meek/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates/

Thanks!

Comment: what does `list.Expression` give you?

Comment: An Expression object but not an Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Comment: Try this: `((UnaryExpression)((MethodCallExpression)q.Expression).Arguments[1]).Operand`.

Comment: Not sure what I can do with this. It gives me an UnaryExpression yes but, how can I get an Expression<Func<T, bool>> from it?

Comment: Actually, `Arguments[1].Operand` is the `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` - you have to cast to `UnaryExpression` to get at the `Arguments` field. LINQPad and it's `Dump` method is helpful for this, as is the [C# Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: But I don't know if that will help you edit the `Where` lambda - `Operand` isn't writable.

Comment: Now, this code: Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> v = (Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>>)((UnaryExpression)((MethodCallExpression)myData.Expression).Arguments[1]).Operand; throws an invalid cast exception because it depends on what has been done with the initial data. It can or cannot already have where conditions added and that will make the Argument[1] either null or not of the proper type. Also, I'm wondering if using these techniques will fire the query on the SQL server...  At least, you pointed me in some directions. I will continue searching for a solution using this.  Thanks! :)

Comment: No, none of these things will cause the query to trigger. Also, shouldn't you know if a `Where` is present before you try to extract and add conditions?

Comment: In my tryouts so far, I have managed to do exactly what you explained in your answer. I was very close to the solution you gave me. See my reply! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is break down the original `IQueryable`, extract the source and query expression and then build a new query expression and then a new IQueryable from the source and the new query expression. If there is no `Where`, just add the condition to the original query.

```
IQueryable<T> q = _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Id == 1);

if(someValue) {
    Expression<Func<T,bool>> newWhereClause = (T x) => x.Status == 1;
    Expression source;

    if (q.Expression is MethodCallExpression qe && qe.Method.Name == "Where") {
        var we = (MethodCallExpression)q.Expression; // get the call to Where
        var wea1 = (UnaryExpression)we.Arguments[1]; // get the 2nd arg to Where (Quoted Lambda)
        var leftExpr = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)wea1.Operand; // Extract the lambda from the QuoteExpression
        newWhereClause = ExpressionBuilder.Or(leftExpr, newWhereClause);
        q = q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(we.Arguments[0]).Where(newWhereClause);
    }
    else
        q = q.Where(newWhereClause);
}
```

Note that this depends on the internals of LINQ and expression trees, and could break at some point in the future.

Comment: I was SO close! The only thing that I will have to watch is when we upgrade frameworks but since then, we will probably have refactored the part where this code is needed for something way more robust and efficient (using FullText search)

Thanks!!

Comment: @Stéphan No problem - fixed where I left an `Accounts` that should been `T` :)

Comment: You also have a typo in the last line of the if block! (wf instead of we) ;)

Comment: @Stéphan Thanks, fixed.